# Firefox is uploading lots of data during startup

Tags: firefox

Firefox is uploading lots of data during startup to servers like `ec2-52-89-171-193.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com.https`. Is there a way to find what data are being uploaded to any particular server and how is firefox uploading my data? Because my default home page in firefox is only google.com but there are lots of websites showing up during tcpdump and through wireshark.

Is there any recommended resources which I can go through to find out more about this?

Comment: firefox support ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox has provided a list of things to try [here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-stop-firefox-making-automatic-connections) to disable connections on startup. The entire list is a bit long and it covers things such as auto-updates, diagnostics, network detection etc. You can try disabling each setting to see if said connection stops.

As you are probably aware, your sample connection points to Amazon AWS cloud service. This means this could be anyone using Amazon's services, including Mozilla. It'll be difficult identifying who this belongs to unfortunately.